# Creating a function that reads from a file, creates an object that is appended to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

As part of my homework, i'm trying to create a function that can read a text file, create an object and then append it to a list. I've got some code below but I keep getting this error:
TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'power' and 'weight'

Sorry, if the code looks a bit wonky, first time posting here.

```
class Collectable:
    def __init__(self, name, power, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.power = power
        self.weight = weight
def read_file(file):
    ls = []
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            x = line.split(" | ")
            ls.append(Collectable(x))
        return ls

p = read_file("file.txt")
print(p)
```

```
file.txt

Mace | 10 | 35
Shield | 3 | 15
```

The output is supposed to return the objects in a list

["Mace", "Shield"]

Comment: `ls.append(Collectable(*line.split(" | ")))`

Comment: Hi Tony, i just tried that but i'm still receiving the same error TypeError: init() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'power' and 'weight'

Comment: @mercurial_s That's just a different presentation of the same issue you described in the comments on my answer.

Comment: Make sure each line contains exactly 3 parts after the split.  In other words, check your input file.  Maybe (temporarily) add `if len(x) != 3: continue` right after your `x = line.split(" | ")` to skip those lines that shouldn't be passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You created your initialization function `__init__()` to accept three parameters (besides `self`):

```
def __init__(self, name, power, weight):
```

However, when you attempt to create an instance, you only pass one value:

```
ls.append(Collectable(x))
```

You expect `x` to contain three values, but your code doesn't know that. If you want to pass the individual items in `x` to the initialization, the simplest method would be to [unpack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) them with a leading `*`:

```
ls.append(Collectable(*x))
```

If you haven't gone over argument unpacking yet, you can also unpack at the assignment step:

```
(name, power, weight) = line.split(" | ")
ls.append(Collectable(name, power, weight))
```

Comment: Hmm, i gave the second bit a shot, however i got a: ValueError - not enough values to unpack, (expected 3, got 1). Do i maybe have to split by something else?

Comment: sorry,  so line 21 is what it's tracing back the error to: name, power, weight = line.split(" | ")

Comment: There could be an unexpected line in your file, or a trailing newline character. You could deal with that by catching the ValueError and ignoring that line, but that's kind of outside the scope of this question.

Comment: oh damn, I tried: x = line.replace("\n","")
      name, power, weight = x.split(" | ")
      ls.append(Collectable(name, power, weight))                             
 to remove the new line character, however, i'm still receiving the same error as before, not enough values to unpack

Answer (score 0):

```
class Collectible:
  def __init__(self, name, power, weight):
    self.name=name
    self.power=power
    self.weight=weight

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.name




def read_file(file):
  ls=[]
  with open(file) as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
      x=line.split(" | ")
      ls.append(Collectible(x[0],x[1],x[2]))
  return ls

read_file("file.txt")
```

Comment: OP is asking to append the class object not instance in the list

Comment: "create an object and then append it to a list" , The output is supposed to return the objects in a list

["Mace", "Shield"]

Comment: @prashantrana is this ok now?

Comment: you are now stroing list of class object, to get to the result no need to add the new function, just iterate over the class object and call name ie `sol = [ i.name for i in read_file('read.txt')]`